# Selecting a JSON object with a colon in the key

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using a third party tool that POSTs a JSON response. It works great, but one of the keys I need to use has a colon in it and I have no idea how to select this object in JavaScript.

For example:

```
{
  "photo": {
    "reg": {
      "id": 50
    },
    "thumb": {
      "id": 51
    },
    ":original": {
      "id": 53"
    }
  }
}
```

How do I select `photo.:original.id`?  I get syntax errors when I leave the colon in, and `undefined` when I try dropping the colon.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

It's simple:

```
photo[':original'].id
```

[Dot/bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

Comment: Thank you!  I'm new to Javascript/JSON, I figured there had to be a simple solution.

Comment: My object contained multiple names with colon, the object also contained an array too, i accessed it like so: 
object['firstname:surname']['person:address'][0];