# How to use jsawk to extract value from property of json object with non alpha numeric characters

Tags: javascript, json, jsawk

Example json file content in file  `/tmp/t`

```
 [
    {
      "name:first"   : "trevor",
      "last"    : "wellington",
      "from"    : "england",
      "age"     : 52,
      "sports"  : [ "rugby", "badmitton", "snooker" ]
    },
    {
      "name:first"   : "yoni",
      "last"    : "halevi",
      "from"    : "israel",
      "age"     : 26,
      "sports"  : [ "soccer", "windsurfing" ]
    },
    {
      "name:first"   : "cory",
      "last"    : "parker",
      "from"    : "united states",
      "age"     : 31,
      "sports"  : [ "windsurfing", "baseball", "extreeeeme kayaking" ]
    }
  ]
```

This works fine
`cat /tmp/t | jsawk -n 'out(this.last)'`

But this does not
`cat test.json | jsawk -n 'out(this.name:first)'`

Likely related to:
[Selecting a JSON object with a colon in the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925760/selecting-a-json-object-with-a-colon-in-the-key)
and
[How do I access these weird JSON items with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644605/how-do-i-access-these-weird-json-items-with-jquery?lq=1)

But
`cat test.json | jsawk -n 'out(this.name[':first'])'` does not work either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
... | jsawk -n 'out(this["name:first"])'
```

`this.name:first` doesn't work because a bare `:` cannot be in object attributes.

For example, given this JavaScript object:

```
x = {
  "name:first"   : "cory",
  "last"    : "parker",
  "from"    : "united states",
  "age"     : 31,
  "sports"  : [ "windsurfing", "baseball", "extreeeeme kayaking" ]
}
```

These are valid:

- `x.last` and `x['last']`
- `x.from` and `x['from']`
- ...
- but only `x['name:first']` (`x.name:first` is not)