# How to access JSON Object key with colon in name

Tags: javascript, json

I need some guidance on how to access this key of a JSON object using Javascript: `"yweather:forecast"`. I tried `json.yweather:forecast` but it throws an error.

```
{
    "yweather:forecast" : [
        {
            "@day":"Wed",
            "@date":"10 Jul 2013",
            "@low":"75"      
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting a JSON object with a colon in the key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925760/selecting-a-json-object-with-a-colon-in-the-key)

Comment: O I see should i remove this question then ? I am new here :(

Comment: No worries, it has been closed. Just try to use the search function before you post a question. Also, when you write the question title it actually shows you possible duplicates...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaScript:

`jsonobject["yweather:forecast"]`

Comment: Sorry , In JavaScript.